# Android Jetpack Compose - access pointer source of PointerEvent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a drawing app using the Compose framework and want to implement custom touch handling that differentiates between finger and stylus inputs.

Currently, I'm trying the pointerInput functions, which are supposedly preferred over the old MotionEvents. My current problem is that I can only figure out how to access the pointer source from MotionEvents. Is there anything equivalent for PointerEvents?